# AWS Rekognition API call per/time limit

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have been searching for a while, but have not found any information on whether there are limits on calls to Amazon Rekognition service.
Does anyone know the numbers, or any source where I can look?

What I want to know is if they limit the number of calls allowed per minute or second. I'm looking for information on the the paid (not free) service tier.

Answer (score 2):

You can find documentation on service limits for Rekognition at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_rekognition.

The limits vary depending on which API you are accessing and from which region. Ex. DetectLabels has a limit of 5 transactions per second in US East (Ohio). You may request a limit increase on these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the limits they have, at no time says anything about maximum number of requests per second as in other services

For example in amazon polly if it says the limits it has per second:
Any 2 transactions per second (tps) from these operations(DeleteLexicon, PutLexicon, GetLexicon, ListLexicons) combined.
Maximum allowed burst of 4 tps.

That's why I believe that it has no operations limit per minute, otherwise I would put it as they do in other services. I am using it to authenticate in the company where I am, that we are 23 and at the moment it has not given me any problems of operations per second.

References:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/limits.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: this information i already saw , but they don't say anything about per/Xtime requests and i'm sure they have some limits on this.